# Is there a method equivalent of removeCallback for Flash ExternalInterface?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, air

I have an Flash SWF application in the browser and I'm using ExternalInterface to communicate to JavaScript document.

In the Flash ExternalInterface API there is an [addCallback](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) method. It adds a function on the browser SWF object. When you call it it creates a method on the SWF object in the browser that JS can call:

```
AS: 
public function myEventListener(event):void {};
ExternalInterface.addCallback("myFunction", myEventListener);

JS: 
// returns "function"
console.log(typeof swfObject.getObjectById('myApp').myFunction);
```

But I do not see any existing removeCallback method. What would be the equivalent to removeCallback?

Here is what I have so far:

```
var application = this[objectId]; // gets the Flash object 
application[callbackName] = null;
delete application[callbackName];
```

Does this look correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call addCallback again, setting the function as null:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("callAlert", null);
```

The documentation mentions this: [ExternalInterface.addCallback()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#addCallback%28%29)

> Note: Repeating addCallback() on an existing callback function with a
>   null closure value removes the callback.